# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am trying to chart stock price data using python, mysql and matplotlib.
The code gets data from a mysql database. That looks to complete successsfully.

The data is converted into a list, then into a numpy array.

I am completely new to matplotlib. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried googling the error message but I've not come across anything useful yet.

The error looks to be coming from this line in the code. Specifically around the fig keyword.

```
**fig,** ax1 = plt.subplot()
```

Here is the full code:

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates, ticker
import matplotlib
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import pymysql
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

ticker = '14D'
start_date = '20190107'
end_date = '20190111'
host = 'localhost'
user = 'user'
password = 'password'
db = 'trading'

def get_data_from_mysql(host, user, password, db, ticker, start_date, end_date):
    # Create empty lists
    date_data = []
    open_data = []
    high_data = []
    low_data = []
    close_data = []
    volume_data = []

    '''
    This function load a csv file to MySQL table according to
    the load_sql statement.
    SELECT * FROM asx WHERE Symbol = '14D' AND Date >= '2019-01-02' AND Date <='2019-01-11'
    '''
    query_sql = 'SELECT * FROM asx WHERE Symbol = %s AND Date >= %s AND Date <= %s'
    args = [ticker, start_date, end_date]
    print('You are in get_data_from_mysql')
    print(args)
    try:
        con = pymysql.connect(host=host,
                                user=user,
                                password=password,
                                db=db,
                                autocommit=True,
                                local_infile=1)
        print('Connected to DB: {}'.format(host))
        # Create cursor and execute Load SQL
        cursor = con.cursor()
        cursor.execute(query_sql, args)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        # Print the results
        for row in results:
            date_data.append(row[1])
            open_data.append(row[2])
            high_data.append(row[3])
            low_data.append(row[4])
            close_data.append(row[5])
            volume_data.append(row[6])
        con.close()

    except Exception as e:
        print('Error: {}'.format(str(e)))
        sys.exit(1)

    # Convert the list items to string before printing them out
    print(' '.join(map(str, date_data)))
    print(' '.join(map(str, open_data)))
    print(' '.join(map(str, high_data)))
    print(' '.join(map(str, low_data)))
    print(' '.join(map(str, close_data)))
    print(' '.join(map(str, volume_data)))

    # Convert the list into numpy arrays
    open_val = np.array(open_data[1:], dtype=np.float64)
    high_val = np.array(high_data[1:], dtype=np.float64)
    low_val = np.array(low_data[1:], dtype=np.float64)
    close_val = np.array(close_data[1:], dtype=np.float64)

    # Matplotlib needs dates in floating numbers before they can be plotted
    data_dates = []
    for date in date_data[:1]:
        new_date = dates.date2num(date)
        data_dates.append(new_date)

    # Create a compacted dataset for the ohlc plot
    i = 0
    ohlc_data = []
    # While i is less that the number of items in the data_dates list
    while i < len(data_dates):
        stats_1_day = data_dates[i], open_val[i], high_val[i], low_val[i], close_val[i]
        print(stats_1_day)
        ohlc_data.append(stats_1_day)
        # Increment the counter
        i += 1

    # Day format for the x labels
    dayFormatter = dates.DateFormatter('%d-%b-%Y')

    # Create a figure and an axis
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplot()
    # Colorup is green, colordown is red. Alpha  = opacity of the candlestick (80pct opacity)
    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc_data, width=0.5, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha='0.8')
    # Data verification check
    '''
    plt.plot(data_dates, open_val)
    plt.plot(data_dates, high_val)
    plt.plot(data_dates, low_val)
    plt.plot(data_dates, close_val)
    '''

    # Format the dates
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dayFormatter)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(10)) # specify the number of ticks in the x axis
    plt.xticks(rotation=30) # rotates the x axis titles by 30 degrees
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('14D')
    plt.title('Historical Data for the period of 07-01-2019 to 11-01-2019')
    plt.tight_layout
    plt.show

get_data_from_mysql(host, user, password, db, ticker, start_date, end_date)
```

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SimpleJapaneseCandlestick_v0.4.py", line 128, in <module>
    get_data_from_mysql(host, user, password, db, ticker, start_date, end_date)
  File "SimpleJapaneseCandlestick_v0.4.py", line 107, in get_data_from_mysql
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplot()
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable AxesSubplot object
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You forgot the `s` in `fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()` (subplot**s** instead of subplot). There are other problems in your code as well, so please always first create a [mcve] and if that doesn't help you solve the issue yourself, you have at least something to post here.

Comment: I see your point regarding Minimal, complete and verifiable example. I would counter that (at least in this instance) the problem could stem from changing from mysql, to a list, to a numpy array. Hence the decision to post the full code. As to the additional problems in my code - I am still learning how to code. I suspect I made many mistakes.

Comment: The problem is a simply typo. You would have found out by creating a [mcve] which consists of the two lines `import matplotlib.pyplot; fig, ax = plt.subplot()`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. And I found a couple of other typos. Same ones you probably saw before. Eg, candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc_data, width=0.5, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha=0.8). And I had to stop using ticker as a variable since matplotlib uses it in this line. 
 ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MaxNLocator(10)). Thank you for your help. Cheers.